# Can't install a Julia package through a proxy connection

Tags: julia

I tried the following command in Julia to install [FixedEffectModels](https://github.com/matthieugomez/fixedeffectmodels.jl), but I'm getting this error:

```
julia> Pkg.add("FixedEffectModels")
INFO: Initializing package repository /root/.julia/v0.4
INFO: Cloning METADATA from git://github.com/JuliaLang/METADATA.jl


ERROR: failed process: Process(`git clone -q -b metadata-v2 git://github.com/JuliaLang/METADATA.jl METADATA`, ProcessExited(128)) [128]
 in anonymous at ./pkg/dir.jl:52
```

I'm using a proxy connection, is it related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The`git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf git://github.com/` solve momentarily but after a server reboot it didn't worked anymore, the best solution found in this [**discussion**](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/pkg-add-through-proxy-fails-on-julia-0-5-windows/687/20) was installing Julia 0.6+ because it can use the environment variables, so the `export` take effects in Julia.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 7, it seemed to me the .gitconfig worked. But are you sure it's in the correct user home directory (C:/Users/Username by default) and that it is really .gitconfig and not .gitconfig.txt (like I managed to do on my first attempt)?

Comment: I'm using an ubuntu and running the julia from ```~/```

Comment: Try using version-0.5

Answer (score 1):

Your home is root??

Look at [this discussion](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/pkg-add-through-proxy-fails-on-julia-0-5-windows/687) could be inspiring.

`export https_proxy=...` and `Pkg.setprotocol!("https")` could probably help?

I also propose to upgrade julia. Because you are using Ubuntu, you could add [this ppa](https://launchpad.net/~staticfloat/+archive/ubuntu/juliareleases):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:staticfloat/juliareleases
sudo apt-get update
```

and you could have julia 0.5.2 (unfortunately it was not updated after 0.6)

But if you trust packages on github then you could probably [download julia 0.6.1](https://julialang.org/downloads/) too. :)

Comment: I tried as root and as normal user, this solved my problem ```git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf git://github.com/``` from the link you shared.